# How do you initialize theMvvmCross SQLite plugin

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am creating a MvvmCross application that requires a DB. I have been following the N+1 KittenDB example.  I no not understand how the initializer for the DataStore ever gets called. I have noted the initializer for the FirstViewModel has it as a parameter.

I run my code and I get

```
Unhandled Exception:
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialise ViewModel for type VrWizard.Core.FirstViewModel
```

My Initializer is

```
private IRepository _repository;
public FirstViewModel(IRepository repository)
{
    _repository  = repository;

}
```

Repository is the my version of the DataStore:

```
public Repository(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
{
    _connection = factory.Create ("vrwizard.sql");
    CreateTables ();
}
```

How do I initialize the Repository?

Don French

Added 9/23

Tis is a stack trace of the error on Android.  I get the same error on iPhone.

```
mvx:Diagnostic:  1.95 Creating ViewModel for ActionMain
[mvx]   2.07 Problem creating viewModel of type FirstViewModel - problem MvxException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter factory of type ISQLiteConnectionFactory when creating VrWizard.Core.Services.DataStore.RepositoryService
[mvx]     at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxLazySingletonCreator.get_Instance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass43.<RegisterAsLazySingleton>b__42 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer+ConstructingSingletonResolver.Resolve () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, ResolveOptions resolveOptions, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.TryResolve (System.Type type, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mvx]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.TryLoad (System.Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterValues, IMvxBundle savedState, IMvxViewModel& viewModel) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
mvx:Warning:  2.07 Problem creating viewModel of type FirstViewModel - problem MvxException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter factory of type ISQLiteConnectionFactory when creating VrWizard.Core.Services.DataStore.RepositoryService
      at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxLazySingletonCreator.get_Instance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass43.<RegisterAsLazySingleton>b__42 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer+ConstructingSingletonResolver.Resolve () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, ResolveOptions resolveOptions, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.TryResolve (System.Type type, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.TryLoad (System.Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterValues, IMvxBundle savedState, IMvxViewModel& viewModel) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialise ViewModel for type VrWizard.Core.FirstViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more information
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModelLocator) <0x00148>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle) <0x0006b>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.DirectLoad (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,System.Type) <0x0008b>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.Load (Android.Content.Intent,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,System.Type) <0x000ab>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle) <0x00137>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions/<>c__DisplayClass3.<OnViewCreate>b__1 () <0x00027>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.IMvxView,System.Func`1<Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel>) <0x00053>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView,Android.OS.Bundle) <0x001d7>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled (object,Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>) <0x000f7>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1<Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>>.invoke_void__this___object_TEventArgs (object,Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>) <0x000ab>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid.Views.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise<Android.OS.Bundle> (System.EventHandler`1<Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>>,object,Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0004b>
[MonoDroid] at Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid.Views.MvxEventSourceActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x00033>
[MonoDroid] at VrWizard.Droid.FirstView.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0001b>
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005b>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.23d26989-db28-4670-bfbb-658531972ead (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
[mono] 
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialise ViewModel for type VrWizard.Core.FirstViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more information
[mono]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState, IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.DirectLoad (IMvxBundle savedState, System.Type viewModelTypeHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.Load (Android.Content.Intent intent, IMvxBundle savedState, System.Type viewModelTypeHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialise ViewModel for type VrWizard.Core.FirstViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more information
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState, IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.DirectLoad (IMvxBundle savedState, System.Type viewModelTypeHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.Load (Android.Content.Intent intent, IMvxBundle savedState, System.Type viewModelTypeHint) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Cirrious.MvvmCross
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your specific case:

You could simply add a line to `Initialize` in your App.cs to allow you to `Register` your `Repository` class as providing a singleton `IRepository` instance:

```
     Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();
```

MvvmCross would then create your `Repository` using an `ISQLiteConnectionFactory` from the plugin, and it would store that `IRepository` reference.

This would then allow MvvmCross to later create your `FirstViewModel`

---

For a more general answer:

This area of 'service construction' is often referred using terms like 'Inversion of Control', 'Service Location' and 'Dependency Injection'.

MvvmCross provides a static helper class `Mvx` which provides mechanisms to allow you to `Register` and `Resolve` classes and instances.

These mechanisms include:

- `RegisterSingleton<IMyInterface>(new MyThing())` which allows you to register an instance of a class as the one-and-only-thing that will implement a particular interface.
- `Resolve<IMyInterface>()` which finds and returns what has been registered for a particular interface
- `IoCConstruct<MyClass>()` which will create an instance of the requested class using `Resolve` to fill in any interface references required for its public constructor.

Plugins - like SQLite-Net - sit on top of this layer and use `Register` mechanisms to make services available for application code to use.

One other commonly used option is that your application code can also choose to `Register` one or more bulk sets of classes using a naming convention - which is why you will often see a block in App.cs like:

```
    CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("Service")
        .AsInterfaces()
        .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

This block simply means "find classes with names ending in `Service` and then register them according to the interfaces they implement". Note that `Service` is just a postfix word here - you can easily use a different naming convention by changing the `EndingWith` line.

This block is included in the Kittens sample - and its `KittenGenesisService` and `DataService` classes rely on this block for their construction - see:

- The App.cs - https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-10-KittensDb/KittensDb.Core/App.cs#L9
- The services - https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-10-KittensDb/KittensDb.Core/Services

---

For more information:

- There's a full article on this in the Wiki in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control
- The Inversion of Control/Dependency Injection is introduced in an earlier N+1 session - see how the tip calculation service N=1 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com
- (advanced) Platform specific dependency injection and plugins are then also further covered in N=31 and there's a wiki article on plugins in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

Comment: That is what I thought. I had the CreatableTypes statement and replaced it with the register singleton one. 

  public Repository(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
  {
   _connection = factory.Create ("vrwizard.sql");
   _connection.CreateTable <Property> ();
  }

I used the N=10 as a guide.

Comment: I used the N=10 as a guide. I just installed it and ran it. It works. If I open the DataService.cs it shows the Linq in red and is not available. If I then attempt a compile it fails.

Comment: Currently at a dead stand still. I want to use this because I feel it is the right thing to do on this multidevice product.

Comment: Rewrote from scratch and got it to work though not sure what is different.

Answer (score 3):

A few tips that might have been overlooked (they are in Stuart's examples):

- somewhere the Sqlite plugin must be initialized, look for the bootstrap classes.

  using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;

  ```
  namespace myapp.UI.Android.Bootstrap
  {
      public class SqlitePluginBootstrap
          : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.PluginLoader>
      {
      }
  }
  ```

Second, check the error more thoroughly. Most of the time more info is provided, which parameter could not be constructed.

Third: constructing multiple instances of your service could lead to errors under certain circumstances of Sqlite settings.

Hope this helps you to getting started.

Answer (score 2):

Yes check your UI project closely.  You need to include the same mvvm packages in them as in your core project.  I was working with monotouch layer today and getting this error.  As soon as I added the SQLite plugin to the Touch UI my problems were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

That is only Because of you have not added the NuGet package of SQLite in the Project which is Containing the View,(Means Windows Phone 8 Project)