# How can I setup Property Injection for MvvmCross tests?

Tags: c#, xamarin, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross' IoC property injection, initialized in my respective `Setup.cs`-classes:

```
    protected override IMvxIocOptions CreateIocOptions()
    {
        return new MvxIocOptions {
            PropertyInjectorOptions = MvxPropertyInjectorOptions.All
        };
    }
```

In my view models I then have several public interface properties like this:

```
public void IDataService DataService { get; set; }
```

Everything works when I run the app, but the unit tests fail because `DataService` is `null`.

How can I set up property injection correctly when using `MvxIoCSupportingTest`?

Answer (score 2):

Got it working based on Stuart's answer, which I had to modify to avoid private fields and methods:

```
    protected new IMvxIoCProvider Ioc { get; private set; }

    protected override void ClearAll()
    {
        // fake set up of the IoC
        MvxSingleton.ClearAllSingletons();
        var iocOptions = new MvxIocOptions {
            PropertyInjectorOptions = MvxPropertyInjectorOptions.All
        };
        Ioc = MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize(iocOptions);
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton(Ioc);
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new TestTrace());
        MvxSingletonCache.Initialize();
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxSettings>(new MvxSettings());
        MvxTrace.Initialize();
        AdditionalSetup();
    }
```

I also submitted a pull request for overriding CreateIocOptions directly, which would make it easier: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/897/files

Answer (score 1):

To override the Ioc options used in MvxIoCSupportingTest, you'll need to override `ClearAll()`:

```
    protected override void ClearAll()
    {
        // fake set up of the IoC
        MvxSingleton.ClearAllSingletons();
        _ioc = MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize(/* YOUR OPTIONS HERE */);
        _ioc.RegisterSingleton(_ioc);
        _ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new TestTrace());
        InitializeSingletonCache();
        InitializeMvxSettings();
        MvxTrace.Initialize();
        AdditionalSetup();
    }
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Test/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core/MvxIoCSupportingTest.cs#L33

It would definitely be nicer if that Test class had a `CreateIoCOptions()` virtual method instead.

Answer (score 0):

It must be showing error:

Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type Viewmodel. You might be  missing :

```
public override void Initialize() {
   CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("Service")
        .AsTypes()
        .RegisterAsSingleton();
}
```

For detailed reference you can check out following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18946672/4373895

Hope this helps you.